# Load models in runtime in Unity3D

Tags: dll, unity-game-engine

i just started to design my new project that will be implemented in `Unity3D`. i must have the ability to load models that is not part of the project at runtime. i looked over on `BundleAssets` and it will not fit my needs because the bundle must be generated before (correct me if i am wrong). the models i want to load will be generated at runtime from a `DLL` so it means that the `DLL` will hand over the model to `Unity3D` in some kind of format. 
what would be the best approach to handle this ?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be considered as two sub-problems:

1. How to load a model in code at run-time?
2. How to generate your assets programmatically and create a Unity
   project out of these assets.

I would assume you are referring to the 2nd, and if not, as it is trivial to do so.

To use tertiary tools (e.g. your DLL), you might be interested in [Unity command line](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html):

```
Unity.exe -createProject <pathname>  -batchmode -nographics ...
```

Where you can run shell commands as above. You can put all the models in the assets/subfolders, and Unity when creating the project, it will load all resources it detected automatically.